# How can I access the tag-name of a jsf composite whitin the composite?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, composite-component

I have a composite (as in xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"). I call it via

```
<comps:cimgx imgId="imA" flav="r" />
```

(for example) on a page. Is there a way to reference all html-objects generated by this composite, client-side via javascript?

Something like

```
window.document.getElementsBy_magic_jsf_tagType("comps.cimagx");
```

Edit: or within the composite as something like

```
#{cc.JSF_tag_type_name}
```

??

Edit2: For the background why I'm asking this, see [Is it possible to add a javascript function to a h:form in jsf2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34817479/4142984)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS knows **nothing** about server side code responsible for producing the HTML output on which the HTML document object model is based. This information has really to end up in HTML in some way. For abstraction, make use of CSS classes.

```
<cc:implementation>
    <div id="#{cc.clientId}" class="comp-cimgx">
        ...
    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

```
var cimgxs = document.getElementsByClassName("comp-cimgx");
```

*(note: [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) is not supported in IE8 and lower, grab [jQuery](http://jquery.com) 1.x if necessary)*

#### See also:

- [Integrate JavaScript in JSF composite component, the clean way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615556/integrate-javascript-in-jsf-composite-component-the-clean-way/)
- [How to make same JSF Composite Component included multiple times to have its own javascript scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29124665/how-to-make-same-jsf-composite-component-included-multiple-times-to-have-its-own/)
- [How to select JSF components using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-jsf-components-using-jquery/)
- [Select all items in Multiple SelectManyCheckBox with dynamic ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229959/select-all-items-in-multiple-selectmanycheckbox-with-dynamic-ids/)